# Selenium Webdriver can't focus

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I can't figure out how to send text to `username`. How can I do that? None of the similar issues at StackOverflow helped. (

Here's the code:

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.className("_test"));
WebElement username = list.get(2);
username.click();
username.sendKeys("johnlennon");
```

The focus is there, but not entering text and quits with the following error:

> org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: unknown error: cannot
>   focus element

Comment: Hope the element is visible. Are there any multiple frames?

Comment: Seems like visible ) don't understand what you mean by multiple frames - elements inside it?

Comment: Focus is there, so I would assume that it should enter the text, but not entering. Is there another function to enter text but sendKeys()?

Comment: You will be able to get what that is, please open the html and look for frames. May not be in focus. By the way, why there is `username.click()` for username if that is supposed to take text input?

Comment: `username.click()` clicks on the input area and focus appears.

Comment: Ok, is that going into the test field then? Have you tried without it? By the way, is the element identified working correctly?

Comment: Same issue when I tried without clicking the area.

Comment: Check with firebug if the identifier used for the locating the web element is right.

Comment: Try printing `username.getAttributes("outerHTML")`. Is that the element you are looking for? You shouldn't need to `.click()` before using `.sendKeys()`

Comment: BTW, are you actually from Kirkland, WA? I used to live there is the reason I'm asking...

Comment: @JeffC, yes. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I ended up and it worked:

```
List<WebElement> username = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id, '-Username')]"));
username(1).sendKeys("johnlennon");
```

Seems like there were several similar elements. Sorry and thanks Rao!